# What are "Difference" and "Delta" in Wireshark RTP Analysis?

Tags: wireshark, voip, terminology

I tried to find this in the documentation, but had no luck. I would love to dig the sources to find out, but I honestly don't have the time. I tried to google this, but either people do not get any reply (like [this one](http://wireshark.org/lists/wireshark-users/200611/msg00169.html) or [that one](http://wireshark.org/lists/wireshark-users/201003/msg00171.html)) or they look at the sources and the epiphany they get prevents them from sharing their newfound knowledge with the mere mortals we are (like here[3] or there[4]).

Is the meaning behind "Difference" and "Delta" in Wireshark RTP analyses and graphs too much knowledge for the world to handle, or could we get a clear answer on that?
(Also, do any of these relate to "Latency", and if not, is there a way to get the latency per packet from a capture?)

Edit: I'm using version 1.2.11.

[3] bugs.wireshark.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=5498
[4] wireshark.org/lists/wireshark-users/201012/msg00035.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting Jaap Keuter from the Wireshark Q&A site:

> Delta is the difference between arrival of this packet vs. the arrival
>   of the previous packet. It's all at the network layer and reflects the
>   packet arrival at the capture interface (where it's timestamped).
>
> Difference tries to tell us something about the relationship between
>   packet arrival and RTP timestamps. It's the (absolute) difference of
>   the packet arrival at the capture interface (where it's timestamped)
>   vs. the expected time of arrival of the packet at the capture
>   interface based on the RTP timestamp.
>
> So, Delta is nice from a networking perspective, but for the RTP
>   receiver the Difference is much more relavant since it influences the
>   depth of the jitter buffer is must maintain to provide an
>   uninterrupted playout.

(Complete answer [here](http://ask.wireshark.org/questions/29008/what-are-difference-and-delta-in-wireshark-rtp-analysis/29033))